# How do I extract the row number from a cell reference in Excel using Applescript?

Tags: excel, applescript

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
          set ac to get address of active cell
-- set rw to row of ac
          log ("Active cell: " & ac & return & "Row from Active Cell: " & rw)
end tell
```

Line 3 will not compile but I need something along those lines.

Comment: It's ugly but: "set rw to last word of ac" seems to work for line 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get at cell and row numbers you can use the `first row index` and the `first column index` from Excel's `range` class.

I recommend you dig through the Excel Applescript dictionary, lots of clues in there to possible syntax to try.

For your case:

```
set rw to the first row index of the active cell
```

Comment: To be honest I find the Application dictionaries very hard to penetrate so far, @adamh. I'm using Script Debugger now which has helped me enormously by being able to drill into variables and see how objects are structured. Hopefully dictionaries will start to make sense soon for me.

Comment: I understand, i often just search them for loose terms of what i'm after, guess it pays to know roughly what something could be called. ScriptDebugger is best thing you could have done for your AppleScripting - good move.

Comment: It's also first time I've used a step/breakpoint debugger and I love it! When I read "Coders at work : reflections on the craft of programming" I thought maybe advanced debuggers are overrated, since many of the coders interviewed in that work don't use them, they get by with log statements like I used to. Wrong, for a novice coder step debugging is very cool.

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil Microsoft AppleScript is a pain compared to other applications. They stray away from what you would expect. I suppose this is because the original scripting implementation was VBA, which is its own can of worms.